# MembershipProvider and RoleProvider - do I need to implement all of the required methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Do I need to implement all the required methods on the `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` if writing a custom one to use the `AuthorizedAttribute` in ASP.NET MVC?

There are a few features that I don't want to implement like `CreateUser` or 'DeleteRole` because they violate the system I will be authorizing/authenticating against.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to implement everything if you never use this functionality. Throwing a [NotImplementedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception.aspx) is always a good way to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing the same thing and you don't have to implement all the methods.

You might want to look at the following website.

http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

Great tutorial for implementing a custom membership provider with ASP.NET MVC!

Comment: actually your tutorial link is exactly what @Darin Dimitrov already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to implement all methods for the MembershipProvider or RoleProvider; if you never use the API for creating, updating, or deleting, then you could throw an exception when used.  These are there in case you do modify user data, and are also used by the Administration web site option in Visual Studio.  So if you use that web site, it quite won't work as expected as it expects these provider methods to be present.

But if all you do is use the controls, then it would be handy to research which API methods these control use and make sure that you have implementations for those.  What I mean is that Login control uses ValidateUser for sure, and may use GetUser too.  It may also call UpdateUser to update the failed logon count, last login date, etc.

HTH.